# passing value via anchor tag in ajax code codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, url

```
success: function (data) {
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    $('#search_result').empty();
                    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                        $('#search_result').append("<tr>"+
                          "<td>"+
                          value.Experience+
                          "</td>"+
                          "<td>"+
                          '<?php echo anchor('site/apply',"Apply") ?>'+
                          "</td>"+
                          "<td>"+
                         value.Id+
                          "</td>"+
                          "</tr>"
                          )
                    })
                }
```

Above is the success details for my search using ajax..I need to pass `value.Id` through the href attribute of anchor tag.How could it is possible for me?

Comment: you can pass the value in `id` or `class` of `<a` tag and get them.

Comment: I didn't get you . .@urfusion

Comment: your question is quite unclear. can you please more elaborate. Show your html too.

Answer (score 1):

I thinks this should work.

```
success: function (data) {
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    $('#search_result').empty();
                    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                        var link = "<a href='<?php echo base_url() ?>site/apply/'+value.Id>Apply</a>";

                        $('#search_result').append("<tr>"+
                          "<td>"+
                          value.Experience+
                          "</td>"+
                          "<td>"+link+"</td>"+
                          "<td>"+
                         value.Id+
                          "</td>"+
                          "</tr>"
                          )
                    })
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 success: function (data) {
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    $('#search_result').empty();
                    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                        $('#search_result').append("<tr>"+
                          "<td>"+
                          value.Experience+
                          "</td>"+
                          "<td>"+
                          "<a href='site/apply/"+value.Id+"''>Apply</a>"+
                          "</td>"+
                          "<td>"+
                         value.Id+
                          "</td>"+
                          "</tr>"
                          )
                    })
                }
```

This method worked . .